# can i disable ModSecurity rule via .htaccess?

Tags: apache-2.2, centos, mod-security, plesk

On new server for my website, a centOS, when i try to upload an image via PHP and the file name contains a special character, like "my'file.jpg", i get a forbidden page and i can't even try to handle the error via PHP

in log files i find

```
ModSecurity: Access denied with code 403 (phase 2). Match of "eq 0" against "MULTIPART_STRICT_ERROR" required. [file "/etc/httpd/modsec/00_asl_zz_strict.conf"] [line "53"] [id "330793"] [rev "2"] [msg "Multipart request body failed strict validation: PE 0, BQ 0, BW 0, DB 0, DA 0, HF 0, LF 0, SM , IQ 1, IH 0, IP 0, FL 0"] [severity "CRITICAL"]
```

before contacting server support team i would like to know if i can disable this rule for some directories via .htaccess  or via Plesk 12 panel

I tried to add this in .htaccess in root folder, found from a similar question, but I get an internal sever error page

```
<Directory /var/www/vhosts/mydomain.com/httpdocs/test-file-upl>
 <IfModule security2_module>
    SecRuleRemoveById 330793        
 </IfModule>
</Directory>
```

in logs i found

```
[core:alert] /var/www/vhosts/mydomain.com/httpdocs/.htaccess: <Directory not allowed here
```

the error seem to appear even if i delete the IfModule security2_module part

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use [`Directory`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#directory) directives in `.htaccess` files.

The scope of settings in `.htaccess` files is already defined by the directory the `.htaccess` file is found in.

In other words the settings in `/var/www/vhosts/mydomain.com/httpdocs/.htaccess` are valid for the directory `/var/www/vhosts/mydomain.com/httpdocs/` and all subdirectories therein.

If you want to apply settings to /var/www/vhosts/mydomain.com/httpdocs/test-file-upl you'll need to put your settings in a `/var/www/vhosts/mydomain.com/httpdocs/test-file-upl/.htaccess` file instead, which would look like:

```
<IfModule security2_module>
    SecRuleRemoveById 330793        
</IfModule>
```

(Or even better, [don't rely on .htaccess files at all](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/htaccess.html#when) and include your settings in your apache configuration files. )

Comment: Thanks! same code without Directory inside test folder works. I can't edit Apache configuration, is a managed server. Does the rule id 330793 referred to my server configuration or is a generic ID?

Comment: As I know you can disable separate rules via plesk UI in Tools&Settings > Web Application Firewall